# Trying to make a directive that uses JsBarcode

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using https://github.com/lindell/JsBarcode to try and insert a barcode onto the page using a directive like :

```
<barcode data=studentData.pid></barcode>
```

Its got the associated directive:

```
.directive('barcode', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
            data: '='
        },
    template: '<canvas id=barcode></canvas>',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
        canvas = element.find('canvas')
        JsBarcode(canvas[0], $scope.data);
    }

};
```

})

I've determined that the data is getting passed correctly but the JsBarcode lib is flipping out on line 46:

```
var encoder = new window[options.format](content);
```

I made the above a directive because I know you're never supposed to manipulate the DOM inside the controller as a best practice. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm an idiot I was missing the JS lib for the barcode styling. Derp.